# Google maps api v3, defining user current location

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

```
function onPositionUpdate(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;

    var markerPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markerPoint,
        map: map,
        title: 'Your Location'
    });
}

function button_clicked() {
    if (navigator.geolocation)
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onPositionUpdate);
    else
        alert("navigator.geolocation is not available");
}
```

This code is running correctly and shows user location. when I try this at home this shows correct address but when I try this at another location this code doesn't show correct address. why? I dont know how this code run exactly(does this code define for IP or other information)

Comment: How far off is the address? Is it possible it just doesn't have the GPS fine tuned enough at the time of the call? Like maybe it can only ascertain your position within half a mile or something. Also, if you do it form a desktop, it doesn't behave the same. I always get a place in California or something, because it doesn't have GPS, wi-fi connections, etc to use to determine my position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if another program can find you. If not, it might be that its not your code which is incorrect:

http://html5demos.com/geo

Some security measures might cause that the client won't share location informations automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onPositionUpdate() );
```

Not sure if your callback has to have brackets or not. It's something I would try.

I also noticed that geolocation takes a little while to narrow down the approximation to a smaller radius. Might have to call **position update**.